# CSV Reader Not reading entire file (python)

Tags: python, csv, filereader

TL;DR - Pulled tweets into a CSV file.  Some contain random invisible escape characters.  CSV reader is "improperly" reading the end of line incorrectly because of this.  What can I do to stop this?

Here is an image of what the line looks like in Notepad++.  The line is much longer than this, but the program treats that black/white "SUB" as End of File, and moves onto the next file in my directory.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRBRY.jpg

[image: It treats that SUB as end of file and moves onto the next file. I dont want this. Ignore that, process the ENTIRE line, and then continue. This isn't the end of my line, this isn't the end of my file.]

Trying to read in a file thats ~300,000 lines.

I suspected some stuff was missing (only keeping track of a few things, so it was hard to notice at first) so I decided to count the lines as it was reading one of my files.

The program stops after the THIRD of these lines.  This is line 2969, 2970  The last line of the 300,000 processed is 2970.

```
Processing Row : 2968
['@HillaryClinton', '16196000', 'NA', 'Brian', 'brianwatkins74', '44', '25', 'Virgina Beach, VA', '0', '0', 'Sun Nov 01 02:17:53 +0000 2015', '@HillaryClinton Trump has MORE followers now!!!! :) Sweet!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!', '6.61E+17', '6.60642E+17', '<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', '1339835893', 'NA']
Processing Row : 2969
['@HillaryClinton', '617660000', 'NA', 'Logan Jackson', 'mischivishlj', '989', '1379', '', '0', '0', 'Sun Nov 01 02:17:46 +0000 2015', 'RT @BookOfTamara: @HillaryClinton @CBSNews this tweet about an article your intern read really shows your dedication to the issue', '6.61E+17', '6.60642E+17', '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', '1339835893', 'NA']
Processing Row : 2970
['@HillaryClinton', '1224300000', 'NA', '\x80\xb3\xda\x18', 'gingasenki', '5', '1', '', '0', '0', 'Sun Nov 01 02:17:43 +0000 2015', '.@HillaryClinton No TPP for Japan nor the World! #\xfd']
```

I've examined the whole file in Excel / Notepad++ and don't see anything really out of place.

The code for processing the file is below :

```
with open(curFile, 'r') as csvFile :
    fileReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')

    header = fileReader.next()

    rowCount = 0 

    for row in fileReader :

        ## Get the index of the UserID_str

        userID_str_index = header.index("userID_str")

        ## Obtain the userID_str

        userID_str = row[userID_str_index]

        listOfIDs[candidateCount].append(userID_str)
```

Only thing I removed was some if/then's that were for error testing which line was causing the stop.

All this is supposed to do is go through all 300,000 lines, and store into a list-of-lists the userID of the current line.

Edit1 : Had python print out the last line it processed, so you can see how python itself printed it, rather than how it looked in my CSV file.

```
Processing Row : 2970
['@HillaryClinton', '1224300000', 'NA', '\x80\xb3\xda\x18', 'gingasenki', '5', '1', '', '0', '0', 'Sun Nov 01 02:17:43 +0000 2015', '.@HillaryClinton No TPP for Japan nor the World! #\xfd']
```

EDIT2: To clarify, this did not error out. It just stopped processing the file, as if it had reached the end! I had it print out each row / the number of the row as it processed through it.  It hits this row (the 2nd one printed above) #2970 according to it, and then no more.  Confirmed theres around 298,000 more for it to go through.

Comment: stopped how, did it error?

Comment: Nope! No error. It just kept processing, and moved onto the next file.

This loops through a number of files in a directory.

Comment: I was wrong about which row it stopped at, updating my above post.

Comment: So it is like it reached the EOF and just moved on? If you open the file and just iterate over the file object how far do you get?

Comment: I get to that line.  It reaches that line, and treats it as EOF.  It has some invisible character in the tweet.  ýzpˆŒ #TPP1 is what it looks like in Notepad++.  Between the y and z is the word SUB in black and white.   Is there a way to use CSV reader and have it skip these?

Comment: Posted a picture in the main post with what it looks like in Notepad++.

Comment: Looks like a sub  control character, where did the data come from?

Comment: I extracted it using twitter's API.  That was just the "text" field of a tweet.  That is, what tweeter deemed as the contents of the tweet.

Comment: Is that the line after the last line it prints? I think changing the encoding might work

Comment: That line with the sub character is the LAST line it reads.  Forgive my ignorance, how would I change the encoding?

Comment: You can open with io.open https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Also, since UTF-8 won't work here (invalid start byte) do you have a recommendation for what I should use? I'm not familiar with encodings, I haven't ever really played around with them.